# Representing "is-a" relationship in mathematical notation

Tags: graph-theory, notation, trees

I need to write an explanation on an algorithm that performs operations on a tree structure. But, I have an uncertainty. How can I write that $b_1$ is a supercategory for $b_2$:

1. $b_1>b_2$
2. $b_1 \succ b_2$

Which notation is the right one? If none, then how can I represent it?

Comment: As far as I know there is no standard notation.

Comment: @M.Winter, one can say that supercategory is a parent node and subcategory is a child node

Comment: I understood this as soon as I read you initial title, befor it was edited away.

Comment: If you interpret your tree as a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), then it would be natural to use $<$ and $>$. But I have seen order relations using every other symbol too, so still no standard.